# How should I sell the self-learned skills that I have not used in my previous jobs?

Tags: resume, applications, work-experience, germany, skills

Almost all positions related to Data Science are asking for skill and experience in some specific tools/software/frameworks etc (besides the relevant theoretical knowledge). 
As a matter of fact, I have the experience of working with some of them during my current or previous job/study.

However, there are few software/frameworks that I learned in my spare time, but I haven't done any work-related projects related to them. So, if they ask me technical questions about them or even give me a task to do during an interview, I can handle it quickly, but I cannot claim that I used them in my previous work experience.

Especially for job positions which directly ask for excellent expertise or knowledge in these tools, can I state that I do posses such qualifications or not?

Comment: Could you make the source of them available, and show the projects using those frameworks when asked?

Answer (score 6):

Take it simple, no need to lie or hide anything.

If you have the experience with a certain tool / framework, feel free to list it as one of your skills. You don't need to associate it with any of your work experience, it's just another skill that you have, which is listed in the Skillset block of your resume / CV.

If they question how you came to posses the skill since you have no work experience related to the skill, tell them you studied and learned on your own, in your spare time.

Comment: Also be sure you can actually show proof of any projects you've built with those tools rather than just a fork of the tutorial page.

Comment: @lucasgcb Very true.

Answer (score 3):

Add them under a section to your CV called "personal projects" or something like that, and describe there how you are applying that skills.

For example, let's say you have created a personal project for learning Spring Boot.

So, under the section "Personal Projects", you could add an item called "Exploring Spring Boot capabilities", then put an one line description of it, followed by a link to github, gitlab or similar public repository.

Not only you will be advertising your skills but will also be providing evidence of them.

Answer (score 2):

> can I state that I do posses such qualifications or not?

Absolutely. Normally, in a German standard CV, your work experience and what you did in which job is a separate block from what skills you possess and how good you are in it. So yes, put it in. If people ask where you used it, just tell the truth.

Comment: My experience is that employers react this truth by not even calling you to interview. My experience is that the best to do if you make any *crap* work/project in the field, including a near-zero paying freelancer project for any no-name company, and then you try to sell that. However, even so will it be hard - it is even super-hard to make them to believe that you are not completely idiot in a technology in what you are working since many years. In general, it is super-hard to make them believe that you are not *vollidiot*. The lack of trust is a terrible shadow of this whole country.